# div positioning is off when changing visibility

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to hide an anchored link to tel with a media query. So far it works as intended, but when I try to replace it with a similar icon and text without the anchor, it gets repositioned a bit out of line (like a 0.5em margin on top I guess). Can't figure out what's going on here.

This is a snippet of my code.

I am also using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

```css
/********************************************
CONTACT
********************************************/

#contact {
 border-top: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
 border-bottom: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.contact-icon-box {
 width: 32%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}
.contact-icon-link {
 width: 1em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #3d7ddd;
 border-radius: 150px;
 font-size: 5em;
}

#contact p {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 margin-top: 1em;
}

#tablet-phone, #facebook-tablet, #email-tablet {
 display: none;
}

#tablet-phone p {
 margin: 0 auto;
}



/********************************************
TABLET ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    #mobile-phone {
     display: none;
    }

    #tablet-phone, #facebook-tablet, #email-tablet {
  display: inline-block;
 }

}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="contact">
 <div class="contact-icon-box">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/miha.sustersic.5"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-social-facebook">
  </div><p id="facebook-tablet">Miha Šušteršič</p></a>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box" id="mobile-phone">
  <a href="tel:+38631535919"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
  </div></a>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box" id="tablet-phone">
  <div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
  </div>
  <p>+386 31535919</p>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box">
  <a href="mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-email">
  </div><p id="email-tablet">sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</p></a>
 </div>
 <p>I am currently working for design and/or development work. If interested, contact me using facebook or email. Please only use phone contact when urgent.</p>
</div>
```

The background-color adjustment is there just to check that the media queries are working.

Comment: I added a CDN link to the CSS for your icons - you can just include it in the HTML section. The icons show up in your snippet now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
#tablet-phone p {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

is overriding the vertical margin in your

```
#contact p {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

And so the non-link paragraph is taking up less vertical space than the link paragraphs, and the vertical alignment is going bottom-up, so the icon moves down to compensate.

You can prevent this by adding a more specific selector to make sure that particular paragraph style isn't overridden:

```
#contact p, #contact #tablet-phone p {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Updated snippet below:

```css
/********************************************
CONTACT
********************************************/

#contact {
 border-top: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
 border-bottom: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.contact-icon-box {
 width: 32%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}
.contact-icon-link {
 width: 1em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #3d7ddd;
 border-radius: 150px;
 font-size: 5em;
}

#contact p, #contact #tablet-phone p {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 margin-top: 1em;
}

#tablet-phone, #facebook-tablet, #email-tablet {
 display: none;
}

#tablet-phone p {
 margin: 0 auto;
}


/********************************************
TABLET ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    #mobile-phone {
     display: none;
    }

    #tablet-phone, #facebook-tablet, #email-tablet {
  display: inline-block;
 }

}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="contact">
 <div class="contact-icon-box">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/miha.sustersic.5"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-social-facebook">
  </div><p id="facebook-tablet">Miha Šušteršič</p></a>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box" id="mobile-phone">
  <a href="tel:+38631535919"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
  </div></a>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box" id="tablet-phone">
  <div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
  </div>
  <p>+386 31535919</p>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-icon-box">
  <a href="mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com"><div class="contact-icon-link ion-email">
  </div><p id="email-tablet">sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</p></a>
 </div>
 <p>I am currently working for design and/or development work. If interested, contact me using facebook or email. Please only use phone contact when urgent.</p>
</div>
```